# c# how to terminate and start a process

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint

In my c# program (using visual studio 2010), I am uploading files to a SharePoint document library, the problem is i am running our of memory, apparently the process "sqlservr.exe*32" is like over one GB of memory. To upload the file, I first read the bytes of the file into a byte[] array. Then upload the array as a file to the document library. I need a way to clear the memory before uploading each file.

The program uploads the files in a loop which iterates in a directory. So is there a way to clear the memory of the byte[] array?

Actually is there a way I can restart the process "sqlservr.exe*32" to free the memory?

This is the code I use to upload:

And the error message I see on the website is (when the problem occurs, which I think is it running out of memory, also sometimes its different files in the message):
The URL 'Test Library/myfolder/file.txt' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace CustomApplicationPage.Layouts.CustomApplicationPage
{
    public partial class CustomApplicationPage : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Check if user posted a file
            if (File1.PostedFile == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Get the directories in the path
                string[] array1 = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\myfolder\\");

                // Declare variables
                string[] temp;
                byte[] contents;
                string dir_name;
                string file_name;
                int i, j;
                int chunk_size = 5;
                int chunk_index = 0;
                int start_id = chunk_size * chunk_index;  
                int end_id = 1 + (chunk_size * (chunk_index+1));

                // Free the memory
                GC.Collect();

                // For each directory in the main path
                for (i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Get directory name
                    dir_name = Path.GetFileName(array1[i]);

                    // Skip this file
                    if (dir_name == "viDesktop_files" || i < start_id || i >= end_id)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Get the site
                    SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://mysite/");

                    // Turn security off
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
                    webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;

                    // Get site root
                    SPWeb spWeb = site.RootWeb;

                    // Get the specified list/library from the site root
                    SPList docLib = spWeb.Lists["Test Library"];

                    // Get all files in the directory
                    temp = Directory.GetFiles(array1[i]);

                    // Create a folder in the list/library
                    SPListItem folder = docLib.Folders.Add(docLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, dir_name);

                    // Activate the newly created folder
                    folder.Update();

                    // For each file in the directory
                    for (j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
                    {
                        // Get file name
                        file_name = Path.GetFileName(temp[j]);

                        // If the file is a .mht file
                        if (file_name.EndsWith(".mht"))
                        {
                            // Read the contents of the uploaded file into the variable 'contents'
                            contents = File.ReadAllBytes(temp[j]);

                            // Add the file with the specified filename in the folder
                            SPFile file = folder.Folder.Files.Add(file_name, contents);

                            // Activate the file
                            file.Update();
                        }
                    }

                    // Turn security on
                    webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;

                    // Close the site
                    site.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you name **your** process "sqlservr.exe*32"? Why would you expect some other process' memory usage will impact your process?

Comment: @Alexei No way. It's sharepoint and sql server (32 bit). I can't answer for the second question.

Comment: "running our of memory" - what is running out of memory? Your process gets OOM exception? OS complains? Just numbers in task manager make you unhappy?

Comment: i added more details and my code above, does this help?

Comment: No it doesn't. Unfortunately you'll have to figure out what is failing yourself instead of randomly assuming "it runs out of memory". Use tracing, check if event log have any exceptions, look in SharePoint logs for cues, attach debugger and see.  Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: Why are you trying to load a file into a byte array and add it instead of just using the form of Add that takes a stream http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414180?

Answer (score 0):

Free the results and close the connection... You can restart the process but there is likely a  larger problem... Try using LINQ and DataContext

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

If you believe you have everything setup correctly then attempt to use the SQL Profiler and see whats going on at the DB Level...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try calling .Dispose() on site, webApp, spWeb, docLib, folder, file and anything else that is disposable.

The memory consumed by other applications will more than likely NOT cause your application to receive an OutOfMemoryException.  Windows uses virtual memory when needed, and would put other applications' memory in the pagefile.  In a 32 bit process, your application should have 2G of memory available (even if you don't have that much ram available).

From what I've seen with OutOfMemory exceptions, they usually result from the clr not being able to give my application a contiguous chunk of memory larger enough for what I'm trying to do, because of fragmentation.

Anyway, you should start by disposing of those things that are disposable.

And, btw...you shouldn't need to call GC.Collect();